# Clojurescript: parseInt-Function with value for radix

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I am new to Clojure and Clojurescript and here is my Problem. In my webpage I have an input form where the input is string. For further computation with these inputs the input should be integer without a leading zero. So for example "09" is not allowed.

The solution in JavaScript would be:

```
parseInt("09", 10) // 9
```

But right now, I am struggling to convert that in my Clojurescript-Code. In my Clojurescript code I already use the parseInt-Function of JavaScript. This works all fine, but I don't know how to add the parameter radix to this specific code:

```
  (defn order
  [round-data]
  (let [form-data (atom {:round/order 0})
        input-data (inputs/make-validated-input
                    {:class-name "order-input"
                     :spec :round/order
                     :placeholder "Bestellung"
                     :transform js/parseInt
                     :on-change #(swap! form-data assoc :round/order (.-value %2))
                     :value-fn #(:round/order @form-data)
                     :invalid-msg "Bitte eine ganze Zahl eingeben."})
        submit-fn (atom #(rf/dispatch [:game/round-commit @form-data]))]
```

At the :transform key I tried a lot of things like

```
:transform #(js/parseInt (.-value %2) 10).
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be %1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `:transform #(js/parseInt % 10)`

- `%2` means the second argument for an anon-fn - so use `%1` or just `%` for the first one
- no need to get the value again in the transform